# EFI bootable USB doesn't show up: do I need bootx64.efi?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, bios, uefi

I'm facing for the first time an issue to boot a USB drive from an EFI mini PC and I'm a bit confused. After reading a lot of threads I did the following:

1. downloaded the .iso (OpenMediaVault by the way)
2. create the bootable USB with Rufus selecting 'GPT for UEFI'
3. try to boot...

The target machine still doesn't show my USB drive in the boot options. I also did:

- `map` from EFI shell shows the files in my USB drive
- I enabled also the "legacy" settings in the BIOS

I read that to be EFI-compatible I need to have `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi` in my removable drive. Of course I haven't.

I don't understand if this file is standard (i.e. can be downloaded somewhere) or has to be provided specifically for the OS I want to load.

Comment: Does your machine have a 64-bit UEFI kernel?  There are lots of budget machines that exist, with 64-bit compatible processors, that are unable to boot into a 64-bit operating system while in UEFI mode due to their firmware.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Did you format your USB drive with FAT32? Try it.